# ssh login stucked

Tags: ssh, connection

I can login in ssh but it stucked somewhat during after pledge notification

```
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-50-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Tue Feb 11 03:20:05 UTC 2020

  System load:  0.45              Processes:                3300
  Usage of /:   59.7% of 1.76TB   Users logged in:          1
  Memory usage: 20%               IP address for enp0s31f6: 188.40.66.243
  Swap usage:   0%

 * Kata Containers are now fully integrated in Charmed Kubernetes 1.16!
   Yes, charms take the Krazy out of K8s Kata Kluster Konstruction.

     https://ubuntu.com/kubernetes/docs/release-notes

521 packages can be updated.
200 updates are security updates.
```

At that the logs above it will be stucked forever and got disconnected.

now this is the error i got from the logs, luckily i am still connected to ssh before the issue came out

```
Feb 11 03:23:34 new-com sshd[4144113]: error: pam_limits(sshd:session): Could not set limit for 'nofile' to soft=41943029, hard=41943029: Operation not permitted; uid=0,euid=0
Feb 11 03:23:34 new-com sshd[4144113]: error: openpty: No such file or directory
Feb 11 03:23:34 new-com sshd[4144174]: error: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc failed
```

what does this went wrong? thank you

Comment: check this https://serverfault.com/a/934051/482932

Comment: @αғsнιη thank you but i can't login with sudo after doing the /bin/bash -i

Comment: I cannot get you mean by _`can't login with sudo`_.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix my issue

```
apt-get install udev
mount -t devpts devpts /dev/pts
```

I had a lead with this when i saw this on the logs

```
E: Can not write log (Is /dev/pts mounted?) - posix_openpt (19: No such device)
```

I just mounted the /dev/pts and it works now